# Give parameters to Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am completly new to Python and have written no script in this language. But I need help with the following line (I know the line is for running the script in the interpreter). I need to run exactly this program where I can do decompile the .gwc file. I don't want to learn Python now, I just want to run this programm in Pycharm.

Here is the line:

```
$ python gwcd.py [OPTIONS] <gwc file>
```

The Options are:

```
-h, --help       show this help message and exit
--output OUTPUT  Output directory where gwcd will store extracted data
--lua            Extract compiled lua file
--completion     Show the completion code
--media          Extract media files
--verbose, -v    Show all data related to the cartridge
--all            Do everything
```

The Question is also for me, where the gwc file has to be stored.

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: The Github Link for the Project is: https://github.com/driquet/gwcd.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you are running this under PyCharm, meaning you made a Run Configuration and you then click the green "Run" button.

If so, edit the Run Configuration and add your arguments to the "Script parameters" field. You might (or might not) need to set the "Working directory" field if you want your gwc file to be relative, instead of supplying the full path.

Comment: Ok, got it, i need to go to the run configuration, so i added the param to the script and placed a .gwc file in the working directory, but then this error appears `gwcd.py: error: the following arguments are required: input`

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Enno/PycharmProjects/gwcd/gwcd.py", line 148, in <module>
    dobj = GWCDecompiler(args.input)
  File "C:/Users/Enno/PycharmProjects/gwcd/gwcd.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.reader = GWCReader(filename)
  File "C:\Users\Enno\PycharmProjects\gwcd\reader.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.file = open(filename, 'rb')`

Comment: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '[--outpout]'
Exception ignored in: <bound method GWCReader.__del__ of <reader.GWCReader object at 0x00958490>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Enno\PycharmProjects\gwcd\reader.py", line 34, in __del__
    self.file.close()
AttributeError: 'GWCReader' object has no attribute 'file'`

Comment: This error ist showing up no matter what arguments i write into the run configuration ([--help],[--all],...)

Comment: Before diagnosing anything in PyCharm, do you have a command-line Python (non-PyCharm) command that works correctly? I don't know GWC so I can't help on that part.

Comment: I never launched via Phyton Console, but I will try on the weekend when school doesn't take so much time. I will mark your answer as the answered, even if its not at this point.